# Connected Unbounded Subset of a Normed Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X, ||.||)$ be a normed vector space and let $V \subset X$ be a connected unbounded set for which $0 \in V$. Show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, then $\exists x \in X$ such that $||x||=\epsilon$.

---

I'm not sure on how to get started. If $V$ is unbounded, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists a $v \in V$ such that $||v|| > \epsilon$. However, I'm not sure on how to use the connectedness of $V$ to get the result. How would one be able to proceed?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Suppose $\epsilon>0$ but there is no $x\in V$ with $||x||=\epsilon$. Then $V=A\cup B$, where $A=\{x\in V:||x||<\epsilon\}$ and $B=\{x\in V:||x||>\epsilon\}$...

Comment: The two sets are disjoint and open in $V$. If we assume $V=A$ (by connectedness of $V$), then we get a contradiction as $A$ unbounded. Else, get another contradiction since $0 \in V$. Is this it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Well I think so - the argument could be phrased better. ($A$ and $B$ are open, disjoint, and both nonempty, hence $V$ is not connected.)